# How do I create a 100.000+ page PDF in Delphi (synPDF or other)

Tags: delphi, synpdf

I am working with equipment that can accept a PDF file as input. In order to test this equipment's performance I would like to create a PDF file containing 100.000 pages or more. Each page containing simple text, some numbers and a barcode I draw using a barcode module.

I am currently using Delphi and synPDF for the job, using the same method as [described here](https://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=370). This works, I can draw the page perfectly fine, but when I get up to around 50.000 pages, I get "out of memory". This is on a 16GB Win10.

I have tried to use a streaming method, similar to [example from mORMot Report](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SQLite3/Samples/05%20-%20Report%20created%20from%20code/Unit1.pas), but this comes to a crawl around 25.000 pages.

Is there a better way than the linked, or a different module, that allows me to create PDF files with 100.000+ pages ? Or is PDF generally not geared for this number of pages ?

Comment: I trust your app is 64-bit so it can actually use all the memory the machine has? Probably not even worth trying, but you could print to the Microsoft virtual PDF printer. But in any case, I don't think PDF documents are meant to be >= 100kpgs.

Comment: The application unfortunately is 32 bit, Delphi 6, so I am limited to some 1GB memory.  I may have access to a 64 bit compiler later and can test there to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: If so it doesn't matter if the machine has 196 GB of RAM! I think you could try to make your 32-bit app "large address aware" to get a bit more RAM though.

Comment: Are you putting the barcode as a bitmap or a vector drawing? The weight of a page is what matters, not the number of pages.

Comment: @Olivier the barcode is Code128 and Datamtrix, it's drawn to a VCLCanvas, so I would estimate it's bitmap. This has given some points to test.

Comment: Can you post a sample PDF with a single page? Also, did you test without the barcode to see how many pages you could get?

Comment: The generation speed initially is much faster without barcode. But even so, creating 50.000 + pages fails without barcode. A sample page with barcode is here: `https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c2e0376aea118c0b52b94d086c3609d220210310121543/b6506f`.

Comment: There is no image in the PDF so the barcodes are vector-based.

Comment: From what you say, I think the generation is not streamed to disk but done entirely in memory.

Comment: You could create two 50000 pages PDFs and use a different tool to concat them to one 100000 pages PDF, e.g. with GhostScript. Not sure whether that can handle 100000 pages though.

Comment: You're using a 100,000 page PDF as a performance test.  Why?  Is this a requirement for the application?  That it can handle files up to 100,000 pages?  That's a big requirement if you don't actually need it.

Comment: With a 32 bit Delphi  application memory fragmentation will make make everything slow to a crawl and cause out of memory errors long before you actually run out of memory.  Can try FastMM over the built in memory manager to get a bit further before it slows down.

Comment: @J... yes, the (industrial) application will be traversing each page, using PDFium library. Reading seems to be fine, just want to check consistent reading over many many hours, and not get performance hit. 

I will try to import FastMM as suggested